# How do you prevent the component from disappearing too soon?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const FlashMessage = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const hideComponent = () => {
        setisOpen(false);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setTimeout(() => hideComponent(), 9000);
    }, [props]);

    return (
        (props.flashMessage === true && isOpen) ?
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <Text style={styles.message}>{props.message}</Text>
            </View> 
        : null 
    );
}
```

I have this Flash Message component in my React Native app, and sometimes, the Flash Message disappears after 2 second. It seems to appear on a random basis and it's probably due to a problem with useEffect and setTimeout, but I have not been able to figure out what might be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you have with `[props]` as dependency doesn't make sense to me.
But you can have an isolated effect for the `isOpen` boolean.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }, 9000);
  }, [isOpen]);
```

Here is a full working example, simplified:

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, [show]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={e => setShow(true)}>Show</button>
      {show && <div>hello</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```